# error while loading shared libraries: libvtkDomainsChemistry-7.1.so.1

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 19.10

I am trying to install FreeSurfer: ftp://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/pub/dist/freesurfer/6.0.0/freesurfer-Linux-centos6_x86_64-stable-pub-v6.0.0.tar.gz

I am following these steps to install FreeSurfer: https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/DownloadAndInstall

When I run following commands:

```
~/subjects$ freeview -v \
bert/mri/T1.mgz \
bert/mri/wm.mgz \
bert/mri/brainmask.mgz \
bert/mri/aseg.mgz:colormap=lut:opacity=0.2 \
-f \
bert/surf/lh.white:edgecolor=blue \
bert/surf/lh.pial:edgecolor=red \
bert/surf/rh.white:edgecolor=blue \
bert/surf/rh.pial:edgecolor=red
```

I get this error:

```
freeview: error while loading shared libraries: libvtkDomainsChemistry-7.1.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried most of the suggestions on prior listings.

```
~/subjects$ sudo apt-get install libvtkDomainsChemistry-7.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libvtkDomainsChemistry-7.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libvtkDomainsChemistry-7.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libvtkDomainsChemistry-7.1'
```

Also, I have tried both,

$ sudo apt install libvtk7.1-qt

and

$ sudo apt install libvtk7.1

Both installed without error. However, when I try Freeview I got exact same error,

$ freeview -v \

> ```
> bert/mri/T1.mgz \
> bert/mri/wm.mgz \
> bert/mri/brainmask.mgz \
> bert/mri/aseg.mgz:colormap=lut:opacity=0.2 \
> -f \
> bert/surf/lh.white:edgecolor=blue \
> bert/surf/lh.pial:edgecolor=red \
> bert/surf/rh.white:edgecolor=blue \
> bert/surf/rh.pial:edgecolor=red
> ```
>
> freeview: error while loading shared libraries: libvtkDomainsChemistry-7.1.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am very new to Linux, any help appreciated!

Comment: What ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: Hello, I am  using Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Have you tried @Olimjon's solution?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Try also `sudo apt install libvtk7.1-qt`

Comment: @Peny, if it did not work, then please edit the question to include the output of the error.

Answer (score 2):

This library is included in `libvtk7.1` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libvtkDomainsChemistry-7.1.so). Just do this:

```
sudo apt install libvtk7.1
```